# Why Todd calls Dirk Gently "a monster"?

Tags: dirk-gently

Since it's about the season finale, obviously spoilers ahead. Just to makes clear, this question is about the ([comissioned by Netflix](https://s10.postimg.org/4lwfnaert/Dirk_Gently_s_Holistic_Detective_Agency_Netfli.png)) [BBC America TV series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4047038/)

> Towards the end of the season, Todd and Dirk travel in time to the events that occurred in the first episode and witness the massacre in the hotel penthouse. They run away from it and the future-Dirk meets the past self. He tells the past-Dirk the catchphrase "Three questions one answer", tells him that the kitten is important and where Todd, his future friend lives.

Later Todd and Dirk have an argue, the former accuses Dirk of lying about the events he knew, that would happen and that Dirk ruined his life, just to have a friend.

What exactly Dirk Gently supposed to lie about?

Comment: There's a Dirk Gently TV series now? Neat.

Comment: @DaveJohnson for most people it would be easier to identify the series with Netflix (which advertises it as "Netflix original series") rather than with BBC America - Netflix comissioned the movie, hence for me its a "Netflix" series.

Comment: Maybe you linked the wrong series then?  Because I would be more confused by calling it a Netflix series that isn't actually available on Netflix, regardless of who "commissioned" it.

Comment: I watched it yesterday on Netflix - 2016 version with Elijah Woods as Todd

Comment: Ah, you must be in not the USA, where we get shafted by Netflix all the time.  Lucky bastard.

Comment: In the U.S., traditional network TV (mainly ABC, NBC, CBS, FOX), cable TV (HBO, SHO, Cinemax, etc.) and streaming TV (Netflix, Amazon, HULU, etc.) are all in the process of getting sorted out. It's definitely an evolving situation. I *think* Netflix and/or Amazon have been working on some kind of deal with the BBC. It's all pretty confusing, but on the plus side there's never been so much excellent and original programming.

Comment: @DaveJohnson It's not as though those of us outside of the US get any *less* "shafted" by Netflix. There are a lot of movies and shows that are, or have been, available on Netflix in the US that aren't available here in the UK.

Comment: @JAB I have to say, that not having seen the series my first reaction isn't "neat", but "Oh FSM, think how many ways they could have screwed *that* up!". Mr. Adams was a pretty special kind of crazy, and I don't really want any inferior crazies messing with his stuff.

Comment: Just FYI there have been TWO unrelated series - in 2012 and now in 2016

Comment: @dmckee if you go in with that attitude (expecting the worst), you'll probably have an okay experience! It's not Dirk how I imagine Dirk, not even close (the other series from 2012 with Stephen Mangan is closer), but the story is kind of fun, and the characters likeable in their own way. In a way I don't mind that they didn't stick to the books because it's easier to imagine this as an entirely different story with a shared character name, which is essentially what it is.

Comment: @delinear as long as the sofa's still stuck...

Answer (score 5):

Todd assumes that,

> since Dirk saw his future self in the past and gleaned a couple of
>  bits of information

that he (Dirk) either knew, or at least should have known, what was going to happen

> (that they would essentially end up travelling back to the past
>  themselves and reliving the events).

He's possibly laying the blame for those who were hurt as a result of those events at Dirk's door, or at the very least he's angry that Dirk kept this knowledge from him - possibly he believes he could have done more to help the victims if he'd been forewarned.

However, I have to say in Dirk's defence, Todd is being very unfair here.

> Todd himself *also* saw his future self in the past, wearing the coat
> and t-shirt he later deliberately picked up. He also heard a snippet
> of his future self's conversation with Dirk. So he basically had the
> same amount of knowledge - seeing his future self, acquiring the items
> his future self had, and hearing a piece of information out of
> context.

Todd revealed none of this information to Dirk, so if Dirk is a monster then Todd is just as guilty. Todd might argue that he was shocked by what he saw and it only made sense to him in retrospect - in fact this is pretty much Dirk's argument in response to his accusation.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to say that Dirk and Todd had the same level of knowledge. Todd knew he'd seen something weird, but only for a second. Dirk had explicit confirmation that he'd travelled back in time. It's also not his "job" to put those pieces of information and come to a conclusion; even with the same information (and I still say Dirk had more), Dirk is far better suited to actually figure out what was going on. Todd was simply along for the ride.

Comment: Well, again, simply "going along for the ride" is exactly how Dirk describes his own "methods", on multiple occasions, so he's really no better placed than Todd. I guess it's really a matter of opinion who had the most information. I mean Todd literally walked in on himself shouting the name of the device that lead to the issues, so arguably he should have worked it out from that, but in any event the point is they both had a very weird (out of context) experience that, realistically, anyone would have struggled to mentally reconstruct into a true series of events.